# Trouble sending HTML using Node.js and Mailgun

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, parse-platform, mailgun

I'm struggling to send HTML in the email. For the testing and to avoid error, I'm using [Mailgun's email templates](https://github.com/mailgun/transactional-email-templates).

I can successfully send Emails, but when I receive them, I see the HTML as plain text. I'm not sure where I made a mistake, since I've been following the doc. Also, I use `mailgun-js` and `mailcomposer` to achieve this goal.

```
function sendEmailNotif(name) {

 var mail = mailcomposer({
   from: process.env.MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS,
   to: '********@*****.com', // My address, for testing purpose
   subject: ' ****** ' + name +' ***** !',
   text: '******* *****',
   html: 'htmlBody should appear here'
 });

 mail.build(function(mailBuildError, message) {

 var dataToSend = {
    to: '*******@****.com',
    message: fs.createReadStream(htmlBody)
 };

 mailgun.messages().sendMime(dataToSend, function (sendError, body) {
    if (sendError) {
        console.log(sendError);
        return;
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent ! ', + body);
    }
  });

});
```

Also, I declared the html like this :

```
var htmlBody = path.join(__dirname, './emailTemplate/alert.html');
```

Additional information: I'm doing this in 'Cloud Code' with Parse Server.

Here is what I receive as an email:
[image: A screenshot of the email I receive]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and why the email isn't sent as .. html.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
function sendEmailNotif(name) {
  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, './emailTemplate/alert.html'), function (err, htmlBody) {
    var mail = mailcomposer({
      from: process.env.MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS,
      to: '********@*****.com', // My address, for testing purpose
      subject: ' ****** ' + name +' ***** !',
      text: '******* *****',
      html: htmlBody,
    });    
    mail.build(function (mailBuildError, message) {
      var dataToSend = {
        to: '*******@****.com',
        message: message.toString('ascii'),
      };

      mailgun.messages().sendMime(dataToSend, function (sendError, body) {
        if (sendError) {
          console.log(sendError);
          return;
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent ! ', + body);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Explanation: `mail.build` sends your callback the correct MIME-encoded body (in the `message` parameter), so you need to actually use it. (You were instead just using the HTML you read from the file.) The fixes I've made are to:

1. Read the HTML from the file and put that into the `html` field when you create your mail with `mailcomposer`.
2. Actually use the value you get from `mail.build`.

Note that I haven't tested the above code, just read the [`mailgun-js` documentation](https://github.com/bojand/mailgun-js). Apologies for any typos/mistakes!

Comment: It works well, and makes much more sense. Thanks for the explanations. 